# How to write this function in one line of code?

Tags: python, list

I have this code that converts all int elemets of a list to strings:

```
def convert(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i] = str(x[i])
    return x
```

How can I write the function in only one line, using map()?

Tried writing the for loop in one line but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `return [str(a) for a in x]`

Comment: `convert = lambda x: [str(i) for i in x]`

Comment: @Lecdi [Avoid named lambdas](/q/38381556/4518341), use a `def` instead. I realize you're answering the question literally, but it's still bad practice.

Comment: Why are you both modifying `x` and returning `x`? [That's confusing and could easily cause bugs](/q/13062423/4518341). And it seems like it's not intentional because you accepted an answer that doesn't modify `x`. Please [edit] to clarify. While you're editing, please add details to the title, something like "How do I convert a list of ints to strings in one line?" [ask] has tips on writing a good title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the shortest way:

```
def convert(x):
    return list(map(str, x))
```

Comment: How to use the map() function?

Comment: It has two parameters: function (the function to be applied on an iterable) and iterable (the iterable you want to apply the function on)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension:

```py
def convert(x):
    return [str(i) for i in x]
```

Comment: That's two lines

Comment: I am assuming the function definition doesn’t count as a line.

Comment: That's a nit-picky thing to flag. You can inline the contents of `convert` here anywhere it's called and it's one line.

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
def convert(x):
    return [str(y) for y in x]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension

```
ints = [1, 2, 3]
result = [str(x) for x in ints]
print(result)

>> ['1', '2', '3']
```